# AWS Rekognition and S3 Storage - image exact matching

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I'm having some issues figuring out how to use Amazon Web Services and their knowledge about "recognition" of images.

The thing I wanna do is upload a list of images to S3 Amazon Storage, and then in my Application scan an image (like it was a QR code), then search with an API from "AWS Rekognition" the image match (currently still not knowing which one). No, I don't need a collection of similar images or so.

The images in the S3 storage will have a label, exactly a link from youtube that I'll specify. This I'll make it in the relational database.

*In resume is: Have a collection of pictures on S3 Storage, send in parameter an scaned image from my application, search for just one match (not many, or a list, just one coincidence) and then get a label incrusted inside the image that result being a match.*

**Question: an API and parameters that I could use from "AWS Rekognition" to do the search of a singular image matching from a list of images**

*Notes: I don't want to use exactly the face recognition, the kind of images I'll upload to the S3 storage and do a search of, will be like family photos or friends poses. So, a facial recognition is interesting but not the thing I could use to do so.*

Techonlogies planed to use:

- Xamarin Forms and C#.
- SQL Server.
- Amazon Web Services (Rekognition and S3 Storage)

Comment: Rekognition only appears to support face comparison.  Is that what you need?

Comment: @Jason not exactly, the facial recognition I think it's not the technology I would use for

Comment: then Rekognition does not appear to offer any useful API you could use

Comment: @Jason have you done something like this before? I'm searching a technology to use, I thought that AWS could have what I'm looking for

Comment: No.  I'm just reading their API docs

Comment: it sounds like you need a custom ML implementation that basically answers "how similar are these two images?" Rekognition is not the right technology for this.

Comment: @jarmod kinda... I want to scan an image, and search for the image matching and get the link that I previously loaded into a relational value assigned to the image in the database

Comment: you could try with the google cloud platform API called Vision API https://cloud.google.com/vision/  they do have functions that could help you like "Assign general image attributes - Detect general attributes and appropriate crop hints. "